# Spring PropertySource refuses to expand a variable more than once

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I am trying to create a spring configuration class in the following way

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"file:${my.dir}/fileone.properties","file:${my.dir}/filetwo.properties"})
@Lazy(value=true)
public class SpringBeans {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        return ppc;
    }

    @Bean.....
}
```

The problem is that the variable ${my.dir} gets expanded so that it finds fileone.properties but it immediately throws

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${my.dir}/filetwo.properties (No such file or directory)
```

I am using spring 3.1.1.RELEASE and Oracle JDK 7

Is this a bug/limitation in the implementation? Is there any way around it?

Also I cannot find a way to set ignore-unresolvable=true in the annotation like you can in the xml, is this done by default with the annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Spring (As mentioned in my comment on the post below). Upgrading to latest 3.X fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can set ignoreUnresolvable like this:

```
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = PropertyLoadHelper.getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

}
```

As a workaround for expanding values.. you can try to use

```
@Value(${my.dir})
private String dir;
```

and then use it in your bean configuration:

```
propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(new ClassPathResource[]{
                new ClassPathResource("config/"+dir+ "filename1" + ".properties"),
                new ClassPathResource("config/"+dir+ "filename2" + ".properties")
        });
```

Comment: Sadly because the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean needs to be static, it cannot access the dir String variable and trying to make that static doesnt work because than the env value is not available yet. Is this a known bug in Spring then?

Comment: try to use some helper wrapper class around PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and then:

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return PropertyLoadHelper.getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(dir);
    }

Comment: But that class would still be static meaning it would still not have access to ${my.dir} variable which is an environment variable and is loaded after the static class is created. Did I miss something?

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in Spring

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9133

Just tried a newer version and it works. :S